# How to time-delay email deliveries?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm currently learning about the Drupal email functions, such as drupal_mail and hook_mail, and hook_mail_alter, and I have a problem before me where I'll need to be able to queue emails for delayed delivery.  For example, an event signup notification that needs to wait for an hour after the event was registered by a user.  And that email has user specific data, so can't be just a generic template email...

I'm using the [MailQ](http://drupal.org/project/mailq) module, mainly for it's logging capabilities, but I wonder if it (or something else) could be modified to add a configurable delay function?

Any ideas?

======================

Some additional thoughts:

There are 2 modules in D6 that are useful for queuing emails, MailQ and Job queue (in Nikit's list below).  They both have the mail queue functionality, which can be very useful, and both have different approaches, strengths and weaknesses- from a cursory investigation.  EG: MailQ has a great logging function, with a very useful admin interface for dealing with categories of mail such as queued, sending, sent, failed etc.  And you can set how many emails to go out with each cron run.

But while Job Queue doesn't have those categories and logging-archiving as far as I can tell, it does allow for prioritizing different jobs, which can be very useful if you have different email types going out simultaneously, such as contact confirmations, event signup confirmations, and "invite-a-friend" emails for example.

So my idea of a perfect queue would have both of those modules integrated (they don't get along very well) with an additional delay function for each job type.

But writing such a thing is way beyond my meager talents, so I'll just have to write a little custom module that is activated by cron, and that will look for flagged contacts with a creation date of at least an hour in the past, and find a way to write the relevant info directly into the MailQ DB table.

There seems to be some collision going on when I have both my new function being triggered by cron, as well as the MailQ function being triggered by the same cron run, so I'm trying to sort out how to cron-prioritize the MailQ over my function- so that my function will add the table data AFTER MailQ has run.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but I did something in D6 before I knew of transactional email services with hook_mail_alter where I loaded the email parameters into a database table, set the message value to null so it didn't send after the hook, and then later a cron job running every 5 mins would check the table and send a couple messages at a time if any where waiting. Once it sent, I flipped the status to sent. You will get a watchdog error saying the email failed to send.

But with this method, you could either call something like Mailgun/Mandrill and send a scheduled email within the hook, or put it in a database table with a timestamp field like strtotime('+2 weeks') and then have a cron job check on the table every x minutes and send when timestamp conditions are met. hook_mail_alter gives you a field to identify the message, so you could have a switch that would only catch specific emails if you want.

If you're comfortable with custom modules, take a look at the Mandrill module. It likely has a more elegant solution for taking over Drupal's email than what I've described above.